# Constraining an expression in LMFIT to 0

Tags: lmfit

I am just beginning to use LMFIT on a manetostatic problem and wish to enforce that a dot product of vectors be zero.  I have defined the parameters (vector components) `n0_x`, `n0_y`, `n0_z`, `a0_x`, `a0_y`, and `a0_z` and given them initial values. Then I define the parameter:

```
param.add('a0dotn0',expr='n0_x*a0_x+n0_y*a0_y+n0_z*a0_z')
```

but `a0dotn0` is given the value of the dot product of the initial vectors `a0` and `n0`.  How do I enforce the constraint that `a0dotn0` is always zero?

Answer (score 0):

The standard recommendation is to provide a complete example to show what you are trying to do.  Without that, anyone trying to help you has to guess what you're doing and might get it wrong.

If you're defining parameters with something like

```
params = lmfit.Parameters()
param.add('n0_x', 1.0)
param.add('n0_y', 0.9)
param.add('n0_z', 0.8)
param.add('a0_x', 0.5)
param.add('a0_y', 0.4)
param.add('a0_z', 0.6)
```

and want these values to be constrained such that  `n0_x*a0_x+n0_y*a0_y+n0_z*a0_z = 0`  then the easiest way to change one of the parameters to be defined to satisfy that constraint, say by replacing that last parameter definition with

```
##  a0_z = -(n0_x*a0_x + n0_y*a0_y)/n0_z
param.add('a0_z', expr='-(n0_x*a0_x + n0_y*a0_y)/n0_z')
```

You might want to ensure that `n0_z` cannot be zero.